Focus cycling of buttons
I am trying to focus cycle through buttons embedded in an HStack running in a tvOS 17.5 SwiftUI app, but after focusing on the 3rd button pressing the right arrow key in the simulator (or right move button on the remote) doesn't move the focus to the 1st button and vice versa.  Can I instruct the focus system to do cycling of focus between these buttons?
import SwiftUI

struct FocusCycleView: View {
    enum FocusableField: String, Hashable {
        case first, second, third
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusableField?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Button 1") {
                // Action for Button 1
            }
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .first)
            
            Button("Button 2") {
                // Action for Button 2
            }
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .second)
            
            Button("Button 3") {
                // Action for Button 3
            }
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .third)
        }
        .onAppear {
            focusedField = .first
        }
    }
    
}

@main
struct MyTVOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FocusCycleView()
        }
    }
}

